# How to add Enable Disable functionality for a referenceBlock in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, enable-disable

I want to add Enable/disable functionality for a `referenceBlock`. `<referenceBlock name="product_recommendations_pdp" remove="false" />`
The `referenceBlock` can be `remove="true"` or `remove="false"` directly form admin-panel for just selecting.[image]

`referenceBlock` is located at `app/design/frontend/ProjectName/store/Magento_ProductRecommendationsLayout/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

Comment: based on system.xml value??

Comment: Yes based on system.xml value.

Answer (score 1):

Use **ifconfig** attribute

**ifconfig** will not work with `<referenceBlock>` tag. So you need to call the block again in your custom layout file and add **ifconfig** attribute with your **config path**. The blocks with same name gets eventually merged as one.

```
<block class="your_block_class" name="your_block_name" ifconfig="section_name/group_name/field_name" template="your_template_path" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a different approach to solve your issue.
I assume that you are using `<referenceBlock name="product_recommendations_pdp"` to add a block or execute an action on the specified block.
You can add the `ifconfig` attribute on your block or action tags.

```
<referenceBlock name="product_recommendations_pdp">
    <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="section_name/group_name/field_name">
        <argument name="setTemplate" xsi:type="string"> your_template_path</argument>
    </action>
    <!-- or -->
    <block class="your_block_class_name" ifconfig="section_name/group_name/field_name">...</block>
</referenceBlock>
```